# Casting NaN into int in a pandas Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have missing values in a column of a series, so the command `dataframe.colname.astype("int64")` yields an error.

Any workarounds?

Comment: `NaN` cannot be represented as Int64 hence the error, you can either convert your values to a string and then substitute the missing values with the string `NaN` or just leave it as floats as this does have support for `NaN`

Comment: What's the current `dtype`? Could you not just use `np.float64`?

Comment: actually it is float64, but it's a decimal, and i want to ultimately take those values and compare to ints in a database (they are ids of some sort)

Comment: You'll have to make a choice about what to do with those values, either set them to some int value like -1 or drop them

Answer (score 0):

The datatype or `dtype` of a `pd.Series` has very little impact on the actual way it is used.

You can have a `pd.Series` with integers, and set the `dtype` to be `object`. You can still do the same things with the `pd.Series`.

However, if you manually set `dtypes` of `pd.Series`, pandas will start to cast the entries inside the `pd.Series`. In my experience, this only leads to confusion.

Do not try to use `dtypes` as field types in relational databases. They are not the same thing.

If you want to have integes and `NaN`s/`None`s mixed in a `pd.Series`, just set the dtype to `object`.

Settings the `dtype` to `float` will let you have `float` representations of `int`s and `NaN`s mixed. But remember that `float`s are prone to be [unexact in their representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Single-precision_examples)

One common pitfall with `dtypes` which I should mention is the `pd.merge` operation, which will silently refuse to join when the keys used has different `dtypes`, for example `int` vs `object` even if the `object` only contains `int`s.

**Other workarounds**

1. You can use the [`Series.fillna` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) to fill your `NaN` values with something unlikely. `0` or `-1`.
2. Copy the `NaN`s to a new column `df['was_nan'] = pd.isnull(df['floatcol'])`, **then** use the [`Series.fillna` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna). This way you do not lose any information.
3. When calling the `Series.astype()` method, give it the keyword argument `raise_on_error=False`, and just use the current `dtype` if it fails. Because `dtypes` do not matter that much.

TLDR;

Don't focus on having the 'right dtype', dtypes are strange. Focus on what you want the column to actually do. `dtype=object` is fine.